# Google Charts: How I can change "Choose a value..." in controlType: CategoryFilter of ControlWrapper

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, google-visualization

I need know how change "Choose a value..." in controlType: CategoryFilter of ControlWrapper

Example:

```js
 // Define a category picker control for the Gender column    
var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control2',
          'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Sexo',
      'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false,
            }
          },
      'state': {'selectedValues': ['']} // this don't solve my problem
        });
```

This show me one select box like this:
[ Choose a value...]
[ Man ]
[ Woman ]

And I need this:
[ Choose sex...]
[ Man ]
[ Woman ]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ui.caption`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls.html) option to change the value displayed when nothing is selected.

Change:

```
  'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false,
        }
```

to:

```
  'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false,
          'caption' : 'Choose sex'
        }
```